Manwha/webtoon where the female lead is killed multiple times and returns each time
I vividly remember looking at this video where a female lead is in a very elegant castle and people are waiting for her but she runs away from the party and breaks her heels to escape, dropping down from the window.
After that she narrates how she's died and been resurrected multiple times, no matter what she does, she keeps dying somehow. I think I remember her saying that she even tried to move away from her country (I remember her in other clothing, like blue clothing leaning closer to... potatoes? I think I'm getting confused.)
I don't remember what happened after that, but I do recall seeing a man stopping her and that's where the video ended.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

This is likely 7th Time Loop: The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy!, a Japanese manga.

If you think being reincarnated once is a big deal, try seven times. From lowly pharmacist to embattled knight, Rishe has lived many lives. This time around, she’s determined to live in the lap of luxury–but there’s just one catch. To make her extravagant dreams come true, she has to marry the prince who killed her in one of her previous lives! It’s going to take every one of the skills she’s honed over multiple lifetimes to accomplish this goal!

I don't believe there is a webtoon version, but it was adapted to anime. It's possible a youtube creator made something similar to a webtoon using anime stills.
The first chapter of the manga has the protagonist recap their past lives while they run away from her fiance, the prince, publicly denouncing them. Each time she dies she returns to this event and lives a different life, including as a merchant, doctor, maid, and cross-dressing to serve as a knight. I don't believe she was ever a farmer or otherwise involved with potatoes. In some or possibly all of her lives she does escape the country.
To save time, she dramatically leaps from a 2nd story then breaks the heels from her shoes.
   
